# Delete email with google apps script matching certain time conditions

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail

Delete gmail received between midnight and 1am matching certain conditions

Comment: You could use a time based trigger to remove them but the best thing to do is to set up the server not to send them in the first place.

Comment: @User8675309 as I said, I need the ones that aren't irrelevant - anything NOT sent around 0100 is relevant. The ones sent at around 0100 are always useless

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a filter that assigns a label to a messages from a server, for example, MyServer.
Then you can use code like this:

```
function delMsg() {
  // Setting the time range for checking
  var FROM = 0; // Minutes after midnight (start of range)
  var TO = 75; // Minutes after "FROM" (length of range)
  var label = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName("MyServer");
  var threads = label.getThreads();
  for (var i = 0; i < threads.length; i++) {
    var messages = threads[i].getMessages();
    var date = messages[0].getDate();
    var hour = date.getHours();
    var minutes = date.getMinutes();
    if ((hour * 60 + minutes >= FROM) && (hour * 60 + minutes <= FROM + TO)) {
      Logger.log(messages[0].getDate());
      Logger.log(messages[0].getSubject());
      messages[0].star();
      // messages[0].moveToTrash();
    }
  }
}
```

In this example messages sent between midnight and 1:15 will be starred.
To remove them uncomment `messages[0].moveToTrash()`

Comment: I'm glad I was able to help you.